# What tools do you use to monitor applications and business-specific data? (apart from Jenkins)

Tags: monitoring, jenkins

Currently, we use Jenkins to run small node.js scripts in order to check if applications are doing what they're supposed to. Like, we have some routines which should run in an interval and we need to check if these routines have run and have done everything we expect.

Why Jenkins? Mostly because we can just login and look at the dashboard and see the health status of all our jobs at a glance; we can set up notifications; and because we don't know other tools to execute our scripts in a "monitoring" way.

But we know we're misusing Jenkins and the problems we have faced (like an attack we suffered which used our Jenkins instance to attack a credit card company and the constant instability) are making us look for another tool (or tools).

But all I could find was performance monitoring tools. What tools do you guys use to monitor things other than performance?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This is a bit too broad for SR. What "things other than performance" do you need to monitor? Do you need graphs, alerts, reports? What OS must it run on? What's your price margin when it comes to paid solutions? Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), and then [edit] your question to fill the gaps.

Comment: Ok, Izzy, thanks for the feedback, I'll look into it and improve my question.